# Oracle Apex 5: Set max height of Interactive Report

Tags: html, css, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an Interactive Report in Apex 5.0 with more than 20 columns.  All the columns won't fit in the window so I have to use the horizontal scroll bar.

The problem is when I have more than 50 rows, the horizontal scroll bar gets displayed at the bottom of the page but outside the window, so I have to scroll down to see the horizontal scroll bar.

[image]

How can I set the 'max height' of an Interactive Report?

Comment: Set the max-height in a a wrapper/container outside table. Ex. `<div class="wrapper"><table></table></div>`

Comment: @LuisP.A.: Please help me to do this on my page
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=40664:2:6975876473448:::::
workspace: quann
username: quann169@yahoo.com.vn
pass: 1qazxsw2

Comment: I make the solution above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you can set maximum report height in attributes

In your Interactive report region go to

> **Attributes>Heading>Set Fixed Header to Region > Set Maximum Report Height to 1000 px**

Comment: I made the max height 400px, this along with the following in the report's "Header Text" provided horizontal and vertical scroll bars within the report body: <div style="height:100%;overflow:auto;"/>

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing class ( .t-fht-wrapper ) and use this rules

**CSS**

```
.t-fht-wrapper{
max-height: 407px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
```

Attention: There is a rule overflow in this class, remove it.